# Menu Driven Java to select between 3 classes. How to combine all these classes under one?

Tags: java, arrays, menu, combinations

So this is from Liangs Java book, the assignments at the end.  These are 3 different questions.  I got each one to work perfectly on their own.  But I am to use ONE file in a menu driven option where Each choice will call upon the class its assigned to.

The menu works and when choosing option 1 that was able to work.  But the remainder 2 i am having trouble renaming them so they can get called upon.  I'm assuming that they don't work because they have their own main(String[] args) and we can't have duplicates of those or have more than one "main."  My question is how would i rename the last 2 so that they can work?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class BorjaTask7 {



    private static Scanner input;
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option = 0;
        while (option !=4)  {
        System.out.print(
                "Main menu\n" +

                        "1: infix to Postfix\n" +
                        "2: Postfix Expressions\n" +
                        "3: Descending Order\n" +
                        "4: Exit\n" + "\n" +
                        "Enter a choice: ");

        option = input.nextInt();

        switch (option) {      
        case 1:         System.out.println("Infix Expression     Postfix Expression");
        System.out.println("  (1 + 2) * 3            " 
        + infixToPostfix("(1 + 2) * 3"));
        System.out.println("   2 * (1 + 3)           " 
        + infixToPostfix("2 * (1 + 3)"));
        break;

        case 2: System.out.println("result = " + postfix.pop());
        break;

        case 3: System.out.println(iterator.next());
        break;
        }
        }
         }

        private static String infixToPostfix(String expression) {

            LinkedList<String> operatorList = new LinkedList<>();

            // Create a Linked list to store operands
            LinkedList<String> resultList = new LinkedList<>();

            // Create a stack to store '('
            Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

            // Insert blanks around (, ), +, -, /, and *
            expression = insertBlanks(expression);

            // Extract operands and operators
            String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");

            // Scan tokens
            for (String token: tokens) {
                if (token.length() == 0) // Blank space
                    continue; // Back to the while loop to extract the next token
                else if (token.charAt(0) == '(') // Push '(' onto the stack
                    stack.push(token.charAt(0));
                else if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '(' && 
                            token.charAt(0) != ')') {
                    // Place operators within "( )" and the 
                    // front to the front of the operatorList
                    if (Character.isDigit(token.charAt(0)))
                        resultList.addLast(token);
                    else if (token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-' ||
                                token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/' )
                        operatorList.addFirst(token);
                } 
                else if (!stack.isEmpty() && token.charAt(0) == ')') {
                    // Add the operatorList to the result
                    resultList.addAll(operatorList);
                    operatorList.clear();
                    stack.pop();
                }
                else if (token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-')
                    operatorList.addLast(token); // Add +, - to the end of list
                else if (token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/') 
                    operatorList.addFirst(token); // Add +, - to the front of list
                else if (Character.isDigit(token.charAt(0)))
                    resultList.addLast(token); // Add digits to result list
            }

            // Format the result string
            String result = "";
            resultList.addAll(operatorList);
            for (String e: resultList) {
                result += e + " ";
            }

            // return result
            return result;
        }

        /** Method Inserts blanks around (, ), +, -, /, and *. */
        public static String insertBlanks(String s) {
            String result = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == '(' || s.charAt(i) == ')' ||
                     s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                     s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/')
                    result += " " + s.charAt(i) + " ";
                else
                    result += s.charAt(i);
            }

            return result;
        } 

        // second class here
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {

            String[] tokens;
            switch (arg.length) {
                case 0: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: 1 5 * 10");
                case 1: tokens = arg[0].split(" "); break;
                default:
                    tokens = arg;
            }

            Stack<Double> postfix = new Stack<>();

            for (String token : tokens) {

                if (isOperator(token.charAt(0))) {
                    evaluate(postfix, token.charAt(0));
                } else {
                    postfix.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
                }

            }

           System.out.println("result = " + postfix.pop());
        }

        private static void evaluate(Stack<Double> postfix, char operator) {
            double num2 = postfix.pop();
            double num1 = postfix.pop();
            switch (operator) {
                case '+':
                    postfix.push(num1 + num2); break;
                case '-':
                    postfix.push(num1 - num2); break;
                case '/':
                    postfix.push(num1 / num2); break;
                case '*':
                    postfix.push(num1 * num2); break;
            }
        }

        private static boolean isOperator(char ch) {
            return (ch == '/' ||
                    ch == '+' ||
                    ch == '-' ||
                    ch == '*');
        }


        // 3rd class


        public class Task1 {
            private static Scanner in;

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                // 

                if (args.length != 1) {
                    System.out.println("Usage: TextFile");
                    System.exit(0);

                }
        String filename = args[0];

        //TreeSet<String>treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();

        TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        try
        {
            in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.nextLine())!=null)
            {
                String[] tokens = line.split("[|\n|\t|\r|.|,|)|(|-|\"]");



                for (int i = 0; i  < tokens.length; i++)

                    treeSet.add(tokens[i]);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }



        System.out.println("\nDisplay words in descending order");


        Iterator<String> iterator = treeSet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

For convenience i put class2 and class3 so you can see whats in there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i forgot to mention that the only user input would be from menu of choice, being 1 thru 4.  After that everything is a line argument from "run configuration"  So this is the final code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class BorjaTask7 {
    private static Scanner input;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option = 0;
        while (option !=4)  {
        System.out.print(
                "Main menu\n" +

                        "1: infix to Postfix\n" + // 16
                        "2: Postfix Expressions\n" + //14
                        "3: Descending Order\n" +
                        "4: Exit\n" + "\n" +
                        "Enter a choice: ");

        option = input.nextInt();



        switch (option) {
        case 1: 

            String exp1 = args[0];
            String result1 = Task16.infixToPostfix(exp1);
            System.out.println("Infix Expression     Postfix Expression");
            System.out.println(exp1 + "              " + result1);

        break;

        case 2: 

            String exp =args[0];
            String result = Task14.infixToPostfixConversion(exp);
            System.out.println("Conversion of infix <-> to Postfix is");
        System.out.println(exp + "                        " + result);

        case 3: 
            String filename = args[0];
            TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
            try{
                input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
                String line;
                while ((line = input.nextLine())!=null){
                    String[] tokens = line.split("[|\n|\t|\r|.|,|)|(|-|\"]");

                    for (int i = 0; i  < tokens.length; i++)
                        treeSet.add(tokens[i]);
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception ex){

            }
            System.out.println("\nDisplay words in descending order");
            Iterator<String> iterator = treeSet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
            break;

        case 4:
            //option = 0;   
        default:
        System.out.print("You have exited. ");
            break;
            }
        } 
        }
    }
```

here are the other classes:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Task16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Infix Expression     Postfix Expression");
        System.out.println("  (10 + 5) * 8            " + infixToPostfix("(10 + 5) * 8 "));
        System.out.println("   10 * (5 + 8)           " + infixToPostfix("10 * (5 + 8)"));
    }

    /** Method converts an infix expression into a postfix expression */
    public static String infixToPostfix(String expression) {

        LinkedList<String> operatorList = new LinkedList<>();


        LinkedList<String> resultList = new LinkedList<>();


        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();


        expression = insertBlanks(expression);


        String[] tokens = expression.split(" ");


        for (String token: tokens) {
            if (token.length() == 0) 
                continue; // 
            else if (token.charAt(0) == '(') 
                stack.push(token.charAt(0));
            else if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '(' && 
                        token.charAt(0) != ')') {

                if (Character.isDigit(token.charAt(0)))
                    resultList.addLast(token);
                else if (token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-' ||
                            token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/' )
                    operatorList.addFirst(token);
            } 
            else if (!stack.isEmpty() && token.charAt(0) == ')') {

                resultList.addAll(operatorList);
                operatorList.clear();
                stack.pop();
            }
            else if (token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-')
                operatorList.addLast(token); 
            else if (token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/') 
                operatorList.addFirst(token); 
            else if (Character.isDigit(token.charAt(0)))
                resultList.addLast(token); 
        }


        String result = "";
        resultList.addAll(operatorList);
        for (String e: resultList) {
            result += e + " ";
        }


        return result;
    }


    public static String insertBlanks(String s) {
        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '(' || s.charAt(i) == ')' ||
                 s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                 s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/')
                result += " " + s.charAt(i) + " ";
            else
                result += s.charAt(i);
        }

        return result;
    }
}


import java.util.Stack;

public class Task14 {
     static int Prec(char ch)
     //this method will return return preference according to the operator
        {
        switch (ch){

        case '+':
        case '-':
        return 1;

        case '*':
        case '/':
        return 2;

        case '^':
        return 3;
        }
        return -1;
        }

     static String infixToPostfixConversion(String expression){

        String result ="";

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i<expression.length(); ++i){
            char c = expression.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
                result += c;
            else if (c == '(')
                stack.push(c);
            else if (c == ')')
            {
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                    result += stack.pop();
                if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                    return "Invalid Expression";
                else
                    stack.pop();
                }
            else
            {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && Prec(c) <= Prec(stack.peek()))
                result += stack.pop();
            stack.push(c);
            }

        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty())
            result += stack.pop();
        return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String exp = args[0];//expression equals line argument 
            String result = infixToPostfixConversion(exp); //the result will equal the function of that expression "changing from infix to post"

            System.out.println("Conversion of infix " + exp + " Postfix is " + result);
        }

        }

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Task1 {
    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: TextFile");
            System.exit(0);

        }
String filename = args[0];


TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
try
{
    in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.nextLine())!=null)
    {
        String[] tokens = line.split("[|\n|\t|\r|.|,|)|(|-|\"]");



        for (int i = 0; i  < tokens.length; i++)

            treeSet.add(tokens[i]);

    }
}
catch (Exception ex){

}
System.out.println("\nDisplay words in descending order");

Iterator<String> iterator = treeSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move all of your functionality out of all three main() methods and into public methods of the same classes.  Each class can still have their individual main() methods (that just delegate to the local public method for functionality), but for the final project, create a fourth class with only a main() method that calls the public methods of the other three classes based on your users' menu choices.

```
static void main(String[] args) {

    Assignment01Class asgn01 = new Assignment01Class();
    Assignment02Class asgn02 = new Assignment02Class();
    Assignment03Class asgn03 = new Assignment03Class();

    String userInput = // code to get user input
    String choice = // code to get user choice
    String result  = '';
    try {
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: result = asgn01.infixToPostfix(userInput); break;
            case 2: result = asgn02.postfixExpressions(userInput); break;
            case 3: result = asgn03.descendingOrder(userInput); break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       // exception handling code
    }

    // code to show result
}
```

Comment: so i tried combining the Main Throw exceptions for the last 2 into the Main one for the entire class to this:

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, Exception{

And i got an error of Unresolved COmpilation Problem